# selective variable definition in a static C library

Tags: c, static-libraries, lib

Im making a C static library file (.lib) for a Graphical LCD based on 8051 Microcontroller. there are some functions and 3 fonts which can be selected before compile(only one font is allowed). the library should contain some different fonts like :

```
#if defined FONT1
const uint8_t code font[size1] = { /* Font1 Data*/ }
#elif defined FONT2
const uint8_t code font[size2] = { /* Font2 Data*/ }
…
```

and the end user may select one desired font by defining it in the given ".h" file. when I tested, it was not possible to do this by writing above code as the library file, just compiles with one defined font which was obvious. on other hand, it's not efficient to load all 3 fonts at once (in the end application) because of memory considerations.
is there a proper way to do so ?

Comment: doesnt it defeat the purpose of a library that each time you want to pick a different font you have to rebuild everything?

Comment: @user463035818 the library contains all fonts. but the end application selects to load only one font. library size doesn't matter, program size does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly split the fonts up in different source files. Each source file would then be built into a separate object file ([*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))) and if your linker is good enough it will discard object files containing symbols not used.

If the unused object files are discarded then they code and data in them will of course not be part of the final linked executable.

Comment: Note that the names of each array would need to differ, so the same symbol isn't exported by each object. The header could be used to determine which of the three names to use (e.g. by `#define`ing `font` to be `font_a`, `font_b` or `font_c` depending on the preprocessor defines).

Comment: there can't be font1, font2, font3 as the internal functions are written with just "font". maybe im misunderstood, but how's the mechanism to select the font in the end application ?

Comment: @TirdadSadriNejad It seems you need a redesign of your library. One thing that could (and should, IMO) change is that you pass the font as an argument to the function that needs to use it. That way those function becomes independent of the actual font used. Then it's easy to use the preprocessor and conditional compilation to "select" font when building the application using the library.

Comment: The idea of @Someprogrammerdude is correct. Each source file has a `font` array defined. The library will now have multiple objects with the same `font` variable and upon linking one will be selected. To force this selection, you could have an init function in each source file _with a s lightly different name_ and you call this function from your code, even if that function just does a return. This will force the linker to select the object with that function from the library.

Comment: There's an alternative way too, which is to still give each array its own variable name, but use linker features to alias the name `font` to one of them in the header file depending on preprocessor directives. The details of how to do that - and if the particular compiler/linker can do it at all, depends on the compiler/linker though.